# (60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: ssl, paypal, opencart

Having problems installing PayPalCommerce in OpenCart,

After installing and trying to connect to PayPal I get this error!

"(60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK"

As anybody else come across problem as the server certs are just fine?

As Stated Server Certificats are fine, was thinking of changing the Curl SSL Veerify to False but that would defeat the whole purpose. And as the latest Security 1.2 (whatever abrevation).

Answer (score 0):

Update your certificate authority bundle so that your HTTPS connection to the PayPal API endpoint can verify the connection is trusted.

[One can be downloaded here](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html), among other places.

---

If your attempted connection is using a specific certificate file rather than a CA bundle, delete the old certificate and either obtain the endpoint's current one to use instead or use CA verification of it